# Happiness, Love, and Death

Tags: translation, spoken-korean, korean-to-english, korean-culture

I have to translate this sentence.

> 사람은 죽을 만큼 사랑하는 사람을 만나거나 죽을 만큼 사랑하는 일을 만날 때 행복합니다.

Note that the translation is preparatory for a live translation; and as such, leading with the same word as the speaker (of the sentence to be translated) is purposed in offering anyone bilingual a landmark of "yes, they are saying the same thing". And of course, the goal of a matching length is so that saying the same thing "takes the same amount of time to say".

Here is my best effort which considers equal length, understanding of what the speaker is saying, and perhaps some generalization about **happiness, love, and death** that are understood, universally, in the cultures of both Korean and English.

> People, when they meet someone that they would die for, are happy loving that person.

I look forward to some alternatives, feedback, or flung monkey poo is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation of the Korean sentence would be:

> People are happy when they meet a person they love, or something that they love so much that they would die for it.

I would translate it more like:

> People are happy when they encounter someone or something they love dearly.